# RAILS: Does ActiveRecord#persisted? actually queries the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Per the documentation, I know it checks wether the object is a **new_record** or **is_destroyed**, but does it do this just based on the objects's current state like having an id already set or overall not being nil? Or does it try to perform a query to see if it finds anything matching?

Comment: See [`destroyed?`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/destroyed%3F) and/or [`persisted?`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/persisted%3F) and compare with the source of [`new_record?`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/new_record%3F).

Comment: The accepted answer covers it well but I must add here (for newer people) that observing the rails console also tells us if a query has accessed the database or not. Check the last paragraph of the answer to get the idea i.e. if no SQL query with the time taken, then there hasn't been a database hit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, `persisted?` does not query the database. It merely checks the values of the object's `@destroyed` or `@new_record` variables.

See https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6-1-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb#L444

```rb
# Returns true if the record is persisted, i.e. it's not a new record and it was
# not destroyed, otherwise returns false.
def persisted?
  !(@new_record || @destroyed)
end
```

`@new_record` is set to `true` when the object is instantiated, then `false` after the record is created. Otherwise it is nil. `@destroyed` is set to `true` after the object is destroyed, otherwise it is `nil`.

At no point does this method hit the database.

If that is your goal, you can use [`exists?`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6-1-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb#L302) to query the database using the ID:

```rb
> User.exists?(user.id)
  User Exists? (5.5ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", "123"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> true
> User.exists?('321')
  User Exists? (0.4ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", nil], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> false
```